# Try catch doesn't work properly in Laravels middleware?

Tags: laravel, error-handling, try-catch, middleware, laravel-6

When using try catch in middleware to override the default exception handler, it doesn't work. The exceptions are not being caught.

```
class NotWorkingTryCatchMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */


    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        try {
           if ( somethingThatCouldThrowAnException() ) {
                $request->newVariable = true;
           }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            dd('Never gets ran, Laravel default handler overrides');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code, you need to catch \Throwable for your try catch to properly work in your middleware. \Throwable is a very broad catch all, ideally you're using your try catch block for code that doesn't need its error to be accounted for. This works on Laravel 5.8

```
class TryCatchMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */


    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        try {
           if ( somethingThatCouldThrowAnException() ) {
                $request->newVariable = true;
           }
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            // do nothing
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            // do nothing
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very bad practice. If you know that there are certain exceptions or throwables you can ignore you should specifically ignore those. Ignoring all exceptions will result in code which is impossible to debug.It is akin to using error suppression which is an anti-pattern

Comment: The reason i'm not listing every exception possible is because the response after acknowledging the error would all be the same, continue the request as normal. That's why they allow you to catch all exceptions, if it served no purpose other than bad practice, why even include it in the language? If I was doing vastly different things upon each exception types, what you're saying would be relevant, but I am not.

Comment: @apokryfos Interested in your response, always willing to evaluate opinion, just don't see it here. :)

Comment: Blanket exception catching is, broadly speaking, bad practice since it is akin to doing e.g. `@somethingThatCouldThrowAnException()` which is bad practice for the same reasons. If `somethingThatCouldThrowAnException` might throw an exception there's usually a finite set of exceptions it *might* throw so you should be catching those. There's always a chance an exception is completely unexpected and something you'd want to know about

Comment: Yeah I agree, if I were going to be performing different actions upon each exception type or if I wanted to be notified about a new exception that came into existence within my code base. However in this scenario it wouldn't matter the difference between Exception1 and Exception2. Fair point?

Comment: I get what you mean . But it depends. In PHP we have a mutable system state meaning that even if you suppress an exception the very fact that it was raised might have altered the system state. If it's one of the exceptions that you expect then you'd know if this happened and how, however if it's an unexpected one then you don't know and the side-effects might just pop up in later parts of the code in ways that don't necessarily make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
catch (\Exception $e) {
```

you should use:

```
catch (\Throwable $e) {
```

to make sure all types will be caught. Both exceptions and errors in PHP 7 extend [Throwable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php)